# Calculating the area between two plots

Tags: integration, graphing-functions, area, discrete-calculus

I have a series of $(x,y)$ data points where all the Y values are in ascending order. Since these are data points, it is possible to fit a linear, exponential or a polynomial trend line. Given a maximum value for Y, I would like calculate the area between the trend line and the maximum Y value. Please refer the image below:

[image]

Any hints would be helpful.

Comment: Let $A$ be the area you want to calculate and $y_{max}$ the max value of $Y$ and $f(x)$ the trend line then: $$ A = \int_0^1 y_{max} - f(x) dx $$

Comment: Or more simply, if your trendline has $y$-value $y_0$ at $x = 0$ and $y_1$ at $x = 1$. then the area you are after is a trapezoid with height $h = 1$ and bases $b_0 = y_\text{max} - y_0$ and $b_1 = y_\text{max}-y_1$. The formula for the area of a trapezoid is $$\frac{b_0 + b_1}2h$$